# Enabling Actuator endpoints for Springboot app and embedded Netty server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

i setup a service which uses spring boot application(for regular rest calls) and a embedded Netty server using NettyReactiveWebServerFactory in a different port (for eureka related calls).
All the actuator related functionality is applied to my main spring boot application but not to my embedded netty server.
Is there anyway where i can enable the actuator endpoints to both servers?
Used versions:
Spring boot version- 2.0.8,  spring webflux
Spring cloud - Finchley.SR2